# How to input a command's result as a string argument in sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

i want to execute a command as follows on my bash terminal:

```
sed -i '6i `sed '1!d' input.in`' out
```

with which i can insert at line 6 of file out (with replacing -i option) the result of the `sed '%1!d' input.in` command. I haven't found anything useful, and have tried both `com`, $(com) and com | sed -i '6i ' out, where `com` stands for `sed '%1!d' input.in`. I don't have any problem changing the syntax of the whole command but i want it to be written in one line on terminal use sed.

Thanks for listening,
awaiting your answer.

For EdMorton:

```
Example Input:

input.in:
into a lake.

out:
Mary was runing around a pond and fell
into a lake.


Mary fell into a what?

Desired Output:
Mary was runing around a pond and fell
into a lake.


Mary fell into a what?
into a lake.
```

Comment: Please try `sed -i "..."` (double quotes)

Comment: can you tell what does `sed '%1!d'` do? on `GNU sed 4.2.2` it gives error as ``unknown command: `%'``

Comment: sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. If you edit your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output we can show you how to do whatever you are trying to do the right way.

Comment: Double quotes were the solution to my problem. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @JohnSig no, they weren't. They might stop you from having a syntax error or maybe even produce the output you expect given some specific input set but they are NOT the solution to your problem.

Comment: @EdMorton I wanted to copy only one line so they are. If you want to copy more line having \n in between you must find another way.

Comment: Whatever it is you want to do, nested calls to sed is not the way to do it.

Comment: @sp asic you are right i put % by mistake --- now it's correct

Comment: @EdMorton the way i implemented it (and it worked) was as follows: `sed '1!d' input.in > temp.of.in  &&  sed -i "6i \`cat temp.of.in\`" out` . If you have a more accurate way to do it, i would be happy to hear it!

Comment: Of course there is a better way but you didn't provide the [mcve] (including concise, testable sample input and expected output) we asked for which is required for us to really help you so instead you got the answer to your [XY question](http://xyproblem.info/) which was how to implement the code you were trying to write instead of how to really address your requirements. If you really want to learn how to do whatever you are trying to do the right way, see [ask] and post a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: To put it another way - there's is no answer to the question "How do I do X" for which a reasonable response is "run sed with negative logic to print the first line of some file into a tmp file then run cat on that tmp file using deprecated backticks and let the shell expand it inline into the middle of another sed command enclosed in double quotes" for any value of X!

Comment: @EdMorton: The problem isn't "for every X". It is precise `sed -i '6i blah-blah'` output means input on line 6 of file output the string "blah-blah" with ovewriting it. On the other hand the command `sed '1!d' input.in` prints to stdin the line 1 of a file input.in. So the "X" was, take a line of a file and input it on anothers file line using sed while using backticks. Then in order to see if there is a better way of doing it i said that i dont have a problem changing command's syntax, and that i just want to use sed for taking and inputing a line.

Comment: @EdMorton: i added an example.

Comment: @JohnSig OK I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `r` on standard input instead of `i`.

```
sed '%1!d' input.in |
sed -i '6r /dev/stdin' out
```

If your platform doesn't support `/dev/stdin` or `/dev/fd/0`, see if your `sed` supports `-` to mean standard input ... or, in the worst case, resort to a temporary file.

As commenters have already pointed out, `%1!d` does not appear to be a valid command in most `sed` dialects, but that is basically unimportant here. (If you mean to print just the first line, maybe you mean `sed '1!d'`, although `sed 'p;q'` does that more efficiently.)

Comment: typo I think.. `sed -n 'p;q'`

Comment: In fact, I think `sed -i '6r/dev/stdin' out < <(sed q input.in)` will work just fine.

Comment: The problem with these approaches is that they don't work for muti-line results from the first / inner `sed` command. You can simplify for that case, but in a way, I think it's lucky that it's not entirely clear from the question whether you can make this assumption.

Answer (score 1):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk.

Given this modified input file

```
$ cat input.in
a Windows folder C:\Windows\Temp
```

Here is what the sed solution you posted in your comments does:

```
$ sed '1!d' input.in > temp.of.in && sed "6i `cat temp.of.in`" out
Mary was runing around a pond and fell
into a lake.


Mary fell into a what?
a Windows folder C:WindowsTemp
```

and here is what an awk solution does more efficiently and accurately and without a temp file:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{x=$0;nextfile} FNR==6{print x} 1' input.in out
Mary was runing around a pond and fell
into a lake.


Mary fell into a what?
a Windows folder C:\Windows\Temp
```

Notice the awk solution preserved the path-separator backslashes while the sed one stripped them. Also note that you should really add `&& rm temp.of.in` to the end of your sed command line to clean up the temp file and you should be using `$(..)` to execute your command, not obsolete backticks.

The awk solution uses GNU awk for `;nextfile`, with other awks you'd replace that with `}NR==FNR{next` or similar but since you are using GNU sed I assume you have GNU awk too.

Note that if you DID have a burning desire to use sed and accept it won't exactly reproduce the input, there are simpler, more efficient ways to do what your current script does, e.g.:

```
sed "6i $(head -1 input.in)" out
```

or even your original idea, just rewritten to remove the obsolete backticks and negative logic of `1!d`:

```
sed "6i $(sed -n '1p' input.in)" out
```

But seriously - just use awk. For anything other than simple substitutions on individual lines it's much more robust, efficient, clear, portable, extensible, etc. etc. than sed.

**EDIT** To address the questions in your comments:

1. *Can you explain the arguments on awk.*
   There are no arguments, just a script that says: If this is the first line read from the first file save it in variable x then move on to the next file. If this is line 6 of the 2nd file print the contents of variable x. For every line of the 2nd file, print it (the `1` is idiomatic but a bit tricky at first glance - it's a true condition so it invokes the default action of printing the current input, equivalent to just writing `{print}`.
2. *how can i replace the out file with the output (without using '>') as the option -i does on sed and avoid printing it to stdout?* Just like GNU sed has `-i`, GNU awk has `-i inplace`. Be careful though because, just like with sed, it applies to **every input file** so if you don't print the contents of the first file then when the script is done the first file will be empty. There's various was to deal with that, including simply printing the lines from file 1 or turning inplace editing on/off in BEGINFILE/ENDFILE blocks, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Extension-Sample-Inplace, but IMHO `awk 'script' file1 file2 > temp && mv temp file2` is the simplest and clearest as well as being portable to all awks/seds/whatever.
3. *Also if there is a multiline solution like "take lines 1 to 4" from "input.in" and drop them on line 6 of "out"?* No problem:

.

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { if (NR<=4) x=x $0 ORS; else nextfile }
    FNR==6 { printf "%s", x }
    { print }
' input.in out
```

I changed the `1` from the previous script to `{ print }` for clarity.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you explain the arguments on awk and also post how can i replace the out file with the output (without using '>') as the option -i does on sed and avoid printing it to stdout?. Thanks in advance. (if you can add them to your answer)

Comment: Also if there is a multiline solution like "take lines 1 to 4" from "input.in" and drop them on line 6 of "out" i would really like to hear it. Thanks again.

Comment: OK, I added answers to your questions at the end of my answer.